# jquery hide div when click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to style div and ul to function like . However, I have a problem that:
1) I only want to toggle the ul that I click and hide the other ul. So I wonder if jquery support some function such as 'not click'?
2) I want to hide all the ul when the mouse is click outside. I did some research, and see other people use mouseup or click on body. But I am not quiet sure how it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();  
    });
  
    $('.select').click(function() {
        var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        var sub = id + '_sub';
        $(sub).slideToggle();
    });
  
    $('body').mouseup(function() {
       if($(this).length == 0) {
         $(this).hide();  
       }
    });
});
```

```css
div.select {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="1" class="select">
  <div class="main">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="1_sub" class="hide">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="select">
  <div class="main">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="2_sub" class="hide">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="3" class="select">
  <div class="main">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul id="3_sub" class="hide">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0mgbsa0b/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide(); //hide in the beginning

    $('.select').click(function() {
        $('.hide').slideUp(200); //hide all the divs
        $(this).find('.hide').slideDown(200); //show the one that is clicked
    });
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if(!$('.select').is(e.target) || !$('.select').has(e.target)){ // check if the click is inside a div or outside
            $('.hide').slideUp(200); // if it is outside then hide all of them
        }
    });
});
```

you can define your `notClick()` function as below:

```
$.fn.notClicked= function(clickPosition){
    if (!$(this).is(clickPosition.target)   && $(this).has(clickPosition.target).length === 0){
        return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
        }
    };
```

and then use it as:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    alert($('.select').notClick(e)); // will return true if it is not clicked, and false if clicked
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like charm. There is one minor thing that the ul can not be closed when we click on the div.

Comment: Not working like a charm on yosemite 10.10.2 firefox 36.0.4. I click once on the box, and it opens and closes...

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide other ul whenever some one clicks on .select div.
Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0mgbsa0b/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hide').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();  
});

$('.select').click(function() {
    $('.hide').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();  
});
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    var sub = id + '_sub';
    $(sub).slideToggle();
});

$('body').mouseup(function() {
   if($(this).length == 0) {
     $(this).hide();  
   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in two concerns you raised, so i will be trying to share some ideas on them:

**1）So I wonder if jquery support some function such as 'not click'?**

personally, to quesiton1

1. i think there is no jQuery event method called .noclick()
2. PPL often use addClass & removeClass to log whether an element got clicked and after marking the element with class="active" , using jQuery selector to select ".active" or using jQuery ":not" selector to select elements that are not marked ".active" ( indirectly finding out those unclicked.)

   3.You might also need to count in click propagation issues. meaning sometimes you click a children container and triggered click event towards all its parent inside.

   ```
    fiddle link: `http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/ctp5jngf/2/`
   ```

   In the above case , if you clicked child box in red, will by default alert1, alert2 if
   you didn't apply a e.stopPropagation() to the click event;

**2) I want to hide all the ul when the mouse is click outside. I did some research, and see other people use mouseup or click on body. But I am not quiet sure how it works.**

for question 2:

1. could be many many ways to do it, you can try blur() //lose focus event trigger.
2. like what you mentioned mouseout, mouseup, add click event listener to outer area all will work for it as long as u can use method in answer1. i see other ppl have posted many answers already as it can be done in many ways.

Comment: Also Thank you too for the interesting concerns you raised. @WhatAName.